# "Are not" or "not be"--- what should I use?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Two sentences to be considered are:

> 1. It's not bad if you rob but **are not robbed.**

> 2. It's not bad if you rob but **not be robbed.**

To me, they both mean the same and the **latter one** seems a bit more formal.

What's the opinion of a native speaker?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The structures before and after coordinators such as *and* and *but* need to be grammatically the same. In your example, *rob* is a finite verb phrase, so the second coordinate needs to be the finite verb phrase *are not robbed*. It cannot be the non-finite *not be robbed*.

If the coordination were in the scope of another auxiliary, eg a modal, both sides would be non-finite, eg:

> if you could rob and not be robbed.